# How to manage assets, storage usage counts, streaming usage counts by tenant wise in windows azure media services?

Tags: c#, azure-media-services

I have an multi-tenant application deployed over windows azure.

Now I want to integrate windows azure media services but I am facing few problems on which I need experts suggestion.

I have already gone through many articles & done enough research but not able to find anything concrete solution.

1. I want to store all videos uploaded by different tenant (client) into separate folder / assets in windows azure media services.
2. I want to track storage space utilization of content uploaded by tenant (client) .
3. I want to track streaming usage counts by tenant (client).

This will help me to show statistics to tenant (client) & bill them accordingly.

Now I found https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/media-services-monitor-services-account/ but this is again incurring charges & too generic & I don't think that I can get data by tenant (client) wise.

Is there are any API available or provided by windows azure through which I can fulfill above?

What are the best practices to achieve the above?

Or

Only way to achieve the above is to maintain separate account for each individual tenant (client)?

Answer (score 0):

Before designing multi tenant application using AMS please read about existing limitations for one ams account - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/media-services-quotas-and-limitations/.

For multi tenant storage billing you can design your system to have one storage account per tenant.

1. Create one storage account per tenant
2. Enable storage analytics to get capacity metrics over billing period

   - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh360996.aspx
3. Associate storage account with azure media service account - See:

   - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn313102.aspx
   - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn306082.aspx.
4. When creating asset explicitly define in what storage account it should be located    - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh974277.aspx#create_an_asset. See parameter StorageAccountName

It is more complicated with tracking streaming usage.There is no turn key solution to get streaming analytics through api. If your tenants using live channels, you have to keep track of their live channel usage yourself based on duration of live channel (See Live Channels section in https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/media-services/).

To deliver on-demand and live video streams to customers you need to decide how you will allocate reserved units per tenants. Each reserved unit has fixed cost and reserved bandwidth. Without cdn integration you will be charged data transfer usage which is calculated per azure media service account. As of now there is no rest api to get data transfer usage for underlying streaming endpoints/channels.

If you will enabled CDN integration, then CDN pricing will be applied. By having dedicated streaming endpoint per tenant will give you ability to have statistics per endpoint. You will have ability to see usage per endpoint in azure portal but not through api.

To summarize above statements:

- It is easy to track storage account usage per tenant through api
- As of now there is no turn key rest apis to get streaming data usage breakdown per entities .